# RestEasy - Mapping list of objects from incoming multipart request

Tags: java, multipartform-data, resteasy

While uploading a Multipart form with some fields as:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="info"

[{"foo":"Foo Data","bar":"Bar Data"}]
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

someId
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

server throws error as:

```
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: text/plain;charset=us-ascii and class type java.util.List
```

Endpoint looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response bulkUpload(@MultipartForm UploadRequestModel uploadRequest) {
  ...
}
```

The model used as:

```
public class UploadRequestModel {

    @FormParam("info")
    private List<InfoModel> info;

    @FormParam("id")
    private String id;

    /**
    * Getters/Setters
    **/
}

public class InfoModel {

  private String foo;

  private String bar;

    /**
    * Getters/Setters
    **/
}
```

Is there any way to unmarshal **info** part to **List** in model?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No hope. Moved on with a flattened model instead of nesting

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we send any complex data in request body it searches helper method that can help to translate request body to java objects.

By implementing those helper method we can achieve the desired results.

As [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) says

> @FormParam Binds the value(s) of a form parameter contained within a request
>   entity body to a resource method parameter. Values are URL decoded
>   unless this is disabled using the Encoded annotation. A default value
>   can be specified using the DefaultValue annotation. If the request
>   entity body is absent or is an unsupported media type, the default
>   value is used. The type T of the annotated parameter must either:

1. Be a primitive type
2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

For example in question, we want to get list of InfoModel object.

As per point no 4, if we implement any of helper method (valueOf or fromString ) inside InfoModel , it should work as well. But I found some how it didn't worked for me.

So I created a wrapper over ArrayList and implemented helper method **valueOf** in ListWrapper class as below. And it worked for me.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
class UploadRequestModel {

    @FormParam("info")
    private ListWrapper<InfoModel> info;

    @FormParam("id")
    private String id;

    /**
     * Getters/Setters
     **/

    public static class ListWrapper<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
        public static ListWrapper valueOf(String json) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ListWrapper obj = null;
            try {
                obj = mapper.readValue(json, ListWrapper.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                obj = new ListWrapper();
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
}

class InfoModel {

    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    /**
     * Getters/Setters
     **/
}
```